# How to rewrite this sub with a loop for i=1 to 12 and while 'txt_Case_Number(i).Text' has a value?

Tags: excel, vba

I've created a search userform that needs to show records under a search of a case number that could have partial duplicate info. Then I make a change to that record and update the sheet with the new info.
Something like this is what I am trying to do:

```
While i = 1 to 12
    .Cells(RowFound(i), "A") = txt_Case_Number(i).Text
    .Cells(RowFound(i), "B") = cmboCase_Status(i).Text
```

Below is what I have and looking to make it as starting to show above.

```
Private Sub cmdMakeEdit1_Click()        
    With Sheets("Sheet1")
        .Cells(RowFound1, "A") = txt_Case_Number1.Text
        .Cells(RowFound1, "B") = cmboCase_Status1.Text
        .Cells(RowFound1, "C") = txtDate_of_Seizure1.Text
        .Cells(RowFound1, "D") = txtSeizure_Type1.Text
        .Cells(RowFound1, "L") = TxtCurr1.Text
        .Cells(RowFound1, "N") = TxtCurr_Dep1.Text
        .Cells(RowFound1, "S") = txtPDH_CourtDate1.Text
        .Cells(RowFound1, "U") = txtDays_PDH_Courtdate1.Text
        .Cells(RowFound1, "V") = txtPC_Received1.Text
        .Cells(RowFound1, "W") = txtDays_464_Filing1.Text
        .Cells(RowFound1, "Y") = txt464_Filed1.Text
        .Cells(RowFound1, "Z") = txtDays_Article36_Filing1.Text
        .Cells(RowFound1, "AA") = txtArticle_36_Due1.Text
        .Cells(RowFound1, "AB") = txtArticle_36_Filed1.Text
        .Cells(RowFound1, "AC") = txtDeclaration_Letter1.Text
        .Cells(RowFound1, "AE") = txtCurr_Sent_ISP1.Text
        .Cells(RowFound1, "AF") = txtAmount_Sent1.Text
        .Cells(RowFound1, "AG") = txtYear1.Text
        .Cells(RowFound1, "AH") = cmbo_Make1.Text
        .Cells(RowFound1, "AI") = cmbo_Model1.Text
        .Cells(RowFound1, "AJ") = cmbo_Color1.Text
        .Cells(RowFound1, "AK") = txtPlate1.Text
        .Cells(RowFound1, "AL") = txtVIN1.Text
        .Cells(RowFound1, "AM") = txtLEADS1.Text
        .Cells(RowFound1, "AN") = txtOwners_Name1.Text
        .Cells(RowFound1, "AQ") = txtLien1.Text
        .Cells(RowFound1, "AT") = cmbLocation1.Text
        .Cells(RowFound1, "AU") = txtFull_Name1.Text
        .Cells(RowFound1, "AV") = txtItem_Desc1.Text
        .Cells(RowFound1, "AW") = txtItem_Model1.Text
        .Cells(RowFound1, "AX") = txtItem_Serial1.Text
        .Cells(RowFound1, "AY") = txtOther_Info1.Text
        .Cells(RowFound1, "AZ") = txtItem_PickedUP1.Text
        .Cells(RowFound1, "BA") = txt_Search1_Type.Text
```

Comment: `controls("txt_Case_Number" & i).`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One of the only ways to loop through Form Control Elements is by initializing a Control and using it in a `For-Each` Loop. Then you could validate the name or type of Control in an If statement, such as

```
Dim ctl As Control

For Each ctl in Me.Controls '<-assuming your button is on the form the rest of the controls are
    If TypeName(ctl) = "TextBox" or TypeName(ctl) = "ComboBox" Then
        'Do Stuff'
    End If
Next ctl
```

Answer (score 0):

You may want:

```
i = 1
While (txt_Case_Number(i).Text <> "" And i <= 12)
    '...
    i = i + 1
Wend
```